Can't open snap store and apps installed with snap
I recently installed Ubuntu, and when I open the Snap Store, the screen (body) is gray and nothing is displayed. I tried to reinstall the Snap Store, but now it doesn’t even open. I also tried to install the apps with Snap in the terminal, but all the apps installed with this method don’t work .
ps : when i try to purge snapd i have this error and output in the end:
Removing snap firefox and revision 4173 rm: skipping
'/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell', since it's on a different 
device dpkg: error processing package snapd (--purge):  installed
snapd package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit stat
us 1 Errors were encountered while processing:  snapd E: Sub-process
/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Thanks in advance...
Ubuntu version : 24.04 LTS

Try snap disable firefox

is already disabled ( ```error: cannot disable "firefox": snap "firefox" already disabled


Where is the Ubuntu version info in the question?

sorry i forgot to add it, it's added now

try sudo snap disconnect firefox:host-hunspell

there is no output in the terminal and nothing change i guess ( the snap store and apps installed with snap like firefox still have the same problem and same error when i try to purge snap )

Please can you add sudo lsblk -f  Is /var on a different filesystem.?  sudo umount /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell also please.
